# How to clear cache when publish sitecore item programmatically in Sitecore 9.3?

Tags: publishing, caching

I have a private method to publish an item to the Sitecore Web database programmatically. It's publishing the item to the Web database but not clearing the cache. I still see the data from the older version of the published item. I was under the impression that the Sitecore publishing module in Sitecore 9.3 version automatically clears the cache when the item is published.

Do I have to explicitly write a line of code to clear the cache or is there a better way to do this?

I did try to add this line but it did not work for me `Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()`

```csharp
private void PublishItem(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
    PublishOptions publishOptions = 
        new PublishOptions(item.Database,
        Database.GetDatabase("web"),
        PublishMode.SingleItem,
        item.Language,
        DateTime.Now)
    {
        UserName = "sitecore\\admin"
    };
    Publisher publisher = new Publisher(publishOptions);
    publisher.Options.RootItem = item;
    publisher.Options.Deep = true;
    publisher.PublishAsync();

    item.Publishing.ClearPublishingCache();
}
```

Comment: It looks like your scalability config has not been enabled properly. Does this work if you publish from content editor ?

Comment: You are doing an Async publish but are not waiting for the publish to finish before clearing the cache. Does this work if you wait before clearing cache?

Comment: Yes, the cache is cleared and the data is displayed on CD from the latest version when I published the item manually from CMS.

Comment: Normally, whether you perform the publish manually or programmatically, there are Sitecore events that clears the cache. When you trigger the publish programmatically, check on jobs.aspx to see when the publish is completed. Once done, check the item

Comment: Where is the cache not being cleared? The same server or a separate CD server? If it’s not being cleared in a CD server then the event queue is not working properly. Also- how are you confirming the item is publishing to web but not clearing the cache? Are you doing an app pool recycle to verify?

Comment: Thank you very much @Jeroen for pointing the issue. You are correct. I had to wait for publish to complete before clearing the cache. I will post the answer with the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how item caching works before hitting the database:
[image]

For my **Sitecore 9.3** scaled solution I use this helper to clear item's cache *(after some item is changed programmatically)*:

```csharp
public static class CacheHelper
{
    public static void ClearItemCache(this Database database,  ID itemId)
    {
        var prefetchCache = CacheManager.FindCacheByName<ID>("SqlDataProvider - Prefetch data(" + database + ")");
        if (prefetchCache != null)
        {
            prefetchCache.Remove(itemId);
        }
        CacheManager.GetItemCache(database).RemoveItem(itemId);
        database.Caches.ItemCache.RemoveItem(itemId);
        database.Caches.DataCache.RemoveItemInformation(itemId);
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var db = Database.GetDatabase("web");
db.ClearItemCache(itemId);
```

But it is strange that `Sitecore.Caching.CacheManager.ClearAllCaches()` does not work in your case. Maybe the problem is not in caches. As @Jeroen mentioned it seems that you clear cache before publish is finished because you use `PublishAsync`. Try to use `async/await` or `ContinueWith` to be sure that your cache is clear when publishing is finished.

Comment: I downvoted as 1) that image is misleading (see my recent posts on the subject) and 2) it doesn’t address the issue the OP is facing. As Hishaam mentioned- their are remote events that handle the cache clearing. Triggering a publish programmatically is fine. We need to know if we’re taking about a single instance or scaled.

Comment: Thank you for downvote). 1) Image illustrates a cycle of storages where does the item come from when it is rendered or gets by Database.GetItem(). It is just for better understanding of caches workflow. 2) Read the title of issue carefully.

Comment: That's fair x3mxray. I still despise the image but yes your answer does address the question posed.

Comment: the correct order to clear caches manually would be prefetch, then data and then item. Also, your two item cache clears are redundant in your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeroen pointed out that we had to wait for the publish to complete before clearing the cache. I used `PublishManager.WaitFor()` method to wait for the publishing to complete. It published the item to CD and cleared the cache. Please see the updated code below.

```csharp
private void PublishItem(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item)
{
    PublishOptions publishOptions = 
        new PublishOptions(item.Database,
        Database.GetDatabase("web"),
        PublishMode.SingleItem,
        item.Language,
        DateTime.Now)
    {
        UserName = "sitecore\\admin"
    };
    publishOptions.RootItem = item;
    publishOptions.Deep = true;
    publishOptions.PublishRelatedItems = true;
    publishOptions.CompareRevisions = true;       

    var handle = PublishManager.Publish(new PublishOptions[] { publishOptions });
    PublishManager.WaitFor(handle);
    item.Publishing.ClearPublishingCache();
}
```